# How do I increase the quantity/yield produced in a batch?

Tags: fiz

I've been asked to make 100 of a type of beer: Z is asking for 100 of improved (700+ quality) Grubb's Premium

Unfortunately, I am producing exactly 95 each time.

I have upgraded my Mash equipment as much as is available (1250 level), and I have been throwing all five of my Craft points against yield.  Do I need to toss some extra points to Craft and then try again, maybe?  Or is there some other way to increase production?

Comment: @kalina: Depends what you mean by "fully upgraded", I'm still levelling up and giving the characters their core stats, i.e. Dexterity, Patience, Intelligence.  I should give someone a Craft point instead of one of the "core" stats?

Comment: there are also employees you can hire that has a chance to improve yield.  A certain pirate has a 30% chance to improve yield by 100%.  My biggest yield in the game was a 4000+ bottle batch

Comment: I was stuck here early in the game. Just toss one more point into craft and you should be able to brew batches of 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only methods of increasing your batch yield are Craft points (acquired via level up), improved brewing equipment, certain recipe augment items (but beware, these will reduce quality), or certain employees.

Have you done the event for the lumberjack? His special ability grants 10% Yield to all batches, which is sufficient to brew 100 units with 5 Craft points to Yield and the Homemade Mash Tun x3.